# bootstrap modal form not submitted the user In rails 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have form inside modal and want to create a user. when I click on submit nothing happens.
How can I submit the modal form and save the content of the modal in other page in rails application with Ajax?

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@getbootstrap">Open modal for @getbootstrap</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"   aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text" class="col-form-label">firstname:</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="text2"></input>

       </div>
       <label for="text" class="col-form-label">lastname:</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="text2"></input>
   </form>
      </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-  dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1224497/Using-AJAX-in-a-Ruby-on-Rails-App) CodeProject as a start.

Answer (score 1):

By clicking submit button the text field value will be passed to the controller via Ajax method

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(){
    alert($("#name").val());
  });
  $.ajax({ 
  type: 'POST', 
  url: 'path/to/controller', 
  data: {'value' : $("#name").val() } 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name"></input>
        <input type="submit" id="submit"></input>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Ragavi